# How to solve a propositonal task question like this?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Hi guys i got a task in propositional logic im a bit stuck in.

Here is the task:

Let the statement variables be:

$H:$ "I ​​eat honey»

$M:$ "I ​​drink milk"

$B:$ "I ​​eat bread"

a) Represent the following statement with statement logical formulas:

• I do not eat bread, if I drink milk and eat honey

• I do not eat bread or honey, but i drink milk

b) Find the statements represented by the following statement logical purposes:

• $( H → M ) → B$

• $H → ( M → B )$

Thanks a lot for help!

Comment: Why dont you improve the formatting of your question and write "I will" in a proper manner.

Comment: sorry for that, my first post here, not so familiar with formatting, but will check it up. thanks for letting me know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given

$H:\;$ "I ​​eat honey,"$\quad M:\;$ "I ​​drink milk," $\quad B:\;$ "I ​​eat bread,"

$(a)$ We'll start with translating to an "in between loglish" before fully translating into propositional logic.

- I do not eat bread, if I drink milk and eat honey. 
  **If** (I drink milk **and** I eat honey), **THEN** **not** (I eat bread). 
   (I drink milk $\land$ I eat honey) $\rightarrow \lnot$ (I eat bread). $$(M \land H) \rightarrow \lnot B$$
- I do not eat bread or honey, but I drink milk. 
   **Not** (I eat bread **or** I eat honey), **and** I drink milk. $$\lnot(B \lor H) \land M$$

For part $(b)$ try to parse the statements, using the fact that $P \rightarrow Q$ means "if P then Q," or "P implies Q", etc, and keeping track of which implication is in parentheses. Does the placement of the parentheses matter? Give the translations a shot; I'll be happy to check your attempts.

Comment: 1. (H → M) → B: I eat bread, if I eat honey then I drink milk
2. H → (M → B): If I eat honey, then if I drink milk then I eat bread

This is what I figured out, thanks alot btw.

Comment: @amWhy: Nice write up! +1

Comment: Dabbish - Yes, indeed, you are correct on part $(b)$.